# Make Neovim to find a path without file extension

Tags: javascript, neovim

I'm working with JavaScript and Neovim. The problem I have is that Neovim needs a specific file extension at the end of the paths to be able to find them, otherwise it can't. So I was wondering if I could detect the file extension without explicitly showing it and be able to jump to that file later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess you need fuzzy file finders like telescope.nvim?